# What is the right way to use TableEntity.Flatten in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to store json object from my API project to CosmosDB using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.
My Json looks like this:

```
{
  "age": 0,
  "type": "network-error",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "body": {
    "sampling_fraction": 0.5,
    "referrer": "http://example.com/",
    "server_ip": "2001:DB8:0:0:0:0:0:42",
    "protocol": "h2",
    "method": "GET",
    "request_headers": {},
    "response_headers": {},
    "status_code": 200,
    "elapsed_time": 823,
    "phase": "application",
    "type": "http.protocol.error"
  }
}
```

And my Cosmos is of type Table API hence I need to flatten it but couldn't find out a way to do it in a most generic way, MSDN documentation doesn't have much about implementation.

Thanks much, appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Is there a reason for using Cosmos DB account targeting Table API? IMHO you should be using SQL API.

Comment: You are right, but it’s an existing DB with other tables in RDBMS schema.

Answer (score 2):

Create a .Net class for your model and pass that to `TableEntity.Flatten`. You can then use the returned Dictionary of flattened key and `EntityProperty` value pairs to create a `DynamicTableEntity` class by specifying the partition and row keys. And you can insert that to cosmos db table storage.

Usage should be similar to how it was used in Table Storage api. Have a look at the unit tests here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/commit/daff940a506b27650901b9b9feb59131ffacce6d

```
ShapeEntity shapeEntity = new ShapeEntity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "square", 4, 4);
            OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext();

            DynamicTableEntity dynamicTableEntity = new DynamicTableEntity(shapeEntity.PartitionKey, shapeEntity.RowKey)
            {
                Properties = TableEntity.Flatten(shapeEntity, operationContext)
            };
```

and you can write this `DynamicTableEntity` into Cosmos DB using the SDK.

To read the flattened `DynamicTableEntity` back into the complex object, when you read it, you need to use `TableEntity.ConvertBack` api.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document you posted above, it will be more appropriate to use the SQL API/Mongo API to store the data in cosmosdb as the document looks sort of JSON.

As you mentioned in the comment if other tables are in relational way , i would recommend you to go through [`data modelling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data) and [design your tables](https://medius.studios.ms/Embed/Video-nc/B19-BRK3054?uc=1)

if you still want to store it in table storage, convert your json to a model and serialize it before inserting using Flatten

```
public class RequestHeaders
{
}

public class ResponseHeaders
{
}

public class Body
{
    public double sampling_fraction { get; set; }
    public string referrer { get; set; }
    public string server_ip { get; set; }
    public string protocol { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public RequestHeaders request_headers { get; set; }
    public ResponseHeaders response_headers { get; set; }
    public int status_code { get; set; }
    public int elapsed_time { get; set; }
    public string phase { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Body body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure how this helps. Cosmos DB Tables (and Azure Tables) are simple key/value (and type) pair store where values are of simple type. In your model, there are some values which are of complex type (request_headers, response_headers). Furthermore, each entity must be of type TableEntity (or ITableEntity) and should have PartitionKey/RowKey members. You simply took the JSON structure and created classes for that.

Comment: you are right! The above Class is a direct conversion of the JSON posted above, however i thought he wanted to serialize the JSON via the code and store it. Yes OP needs to implement TableEntity and add customize properties before inserting to table storage

Comment: And any thoughts on how to use TableEntity.Flatten ?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/dlmelendez/identityazuretable/blob/966cbb5b961b644bbb7d8f86b94db26c2df1d795/src/ElCamino.AspNetCore.Identity.AzureTable/UserStore.cs

Comment: @Sajeetharan By any chance you have tried using 2 different table types under one container ? For eg Table API with SQL API ?

Comment: its not possible, when you create account you need to mention the API type whether SQL or Table